# Can i hash hetrogenous function to undered_map in c++

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have bunch of heterogeneous function , i want to use std::unordered_map for calling that function so that we don't need to maintain a long switch case list.

This is just an example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

void hello()
{
  cout << "hello"<<endl;
}

int hello1()
{
   cout << "hello1"<<endl;
   return 1;
}

int hello2(int x)
{
    cout << "hello2" << endl;
    cout << x;    
    return x;
}


int main()
{
    unordered_map<string, void*> map;

    map["hello"] = (void*)hello;
    map["hello1"] = (void*)hello1;
    map["hello2"] = (void*)hello2;  

    if(map.find("hello2") != map.end())
    {
       func = map["hello2"].second;
    } 

    cout << reinterpret_cast<int(*)(int)>(map["hello2"])(2);
    cout <<endl;
    cout << reinterpret_cast<int(*)()>(map["hello1"]);

}
```

But even after storing them (in void pointer), at calling time we have to change its type , is there any way i can do it better.

Comment: When you write a function call in the source code, you need to pass arguments and optionally take care of a returned value. How would you want to do this if you don't know which arguments the function accepts and which value it returns?

Comment: How do you know which arguments to supply? This is always the problem with heterogeneous stuff - you can't really get rid of the switch because you have left the type system and can't do anything useful outside of it.

Comment: You may need to checkout `std::function` & `std::any`, but c++ is a strongly typed language, this will make your program buggy if not handled properly.

Comment: @DanielLangr getting your point , we have to keep the switch , i will move it to header file though in my main project, thanks

Comment: @WeiGuo `std::function` does not allow to store heterogenous functions into its instance.

Comment: @DanielLangr I mean combine the `std::function` & `std::any`. for example, the function parameters and return value are all std::any type. Of course, you need some abstraction.

Comment: Maybe you can steal a page from Qt's book. Their `moc` compiler analyzes a class/struct definition and generates an appropriate switch statement for all slots and functions marked with `Q_INVOKABLE`. As a user you can then simply use [QMetaObject::invokeMethod](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) to do both the lookup and the invocation.

Answer (score 0):

> But even after storing them (in void pointer), at calling time we have
>   to change its type , is there any way i can do it better ?

Yes, for the heterogeneous function types you can for example use `std::variant` or `std::any` to store multiple type single value, union like behavior.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any

In your example, it would be declared like this:

```
std::variant<std::function<int()>, std::function<int(int)> >
```

In particular, using the `std::variant` the cast can go away completely (but it may feel like a switch).

You may also find it more convenient, flexible and safer to use a `std::function` instead of the raw function pointer.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function